# Two spinners change text in TextView

Tags: java, android, blackjack, android-toast

I'm trying to make this android app and I have some problems. I want to pick a card number in my left spinner, and in the right spinner is my dealers hand, and I pick a card number there aswell.(see Image below)

[image: My app]

I can change my cards and the image updates no problem. But when I pick ex 17 and 2, how do I change the text in my Textview? I have a TextView, but cleared the text. 
I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
if(plHand.equals("8") && dlHand.equals("2") || dlHand.equals("3")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "IT WORKS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I made a Toast just to check if something happens. But nothing happens. But how do I do it? `plHand` and `dlHand` is a String Array. I also tried this

```
if(sp1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("17") && (sp2).getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Ace"){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IT WORKS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Hope you guys know what to do!

EDIT: added more code

```
final String[] plHand = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourHand_array);
final String[] dlHand = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dealerHand_array);

final Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

The text I want to change is in a String Array aswell, but I don't have to use the String Array, if there is an easier way!

EDIT!!: It works now! Full code is here! http://pastebin.com/g3M2wbtL

Comment: did you debug the code? what is this value when cursor on it **sp1.getSelectedItem().toString()** and **(sp2).getSelectedItem().toString()** and **plHand** and **dlHand**

Comment: I can't figure out the debugger, sorry.

Comment: what you mean when you say you cant figure out the debugger? it is on eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attach the same `OnItemSelectedListener` to both spinners like the following:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String plHandText = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String dlHandText = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if ("17".equals(plHandText) && "2".equals(dlHandText)){
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "It works!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, first of all I don't have "getActivity" and I have already defined my plHand, see link http://pastebin.com/JtZf0XiA

Comment: No sorry, still don't show a Toast. Should I make this code in my onCreate method? Most of my code in my onCreate method is here http://pastebin.com/ZfHhzRXg

Comment: @Lobbe because you have your own spinners `sp1` and `sp2`, you should use them with listener. Ok, modified code once again

Comment: So you want me to remove the lines of code? it's because I use ´sp1´ and ´sp2´ further down my code. But even though I did what you said with sp1.setonitemselected.... it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Lobbe just add this code after `sp2.setAdapter(ar2);`, should work

Comment: @Lobbe no. please take a look at my code carefully, you don't need additional spinners, you have your own `sp1` and `sp2`

Comment: Still doesn't work, I copied your code now http://pastebin.com/xNMG1jb1 and here are some more code, Don't know if that helps you.

Comment: @Lobbe after `/* Shows Players card! */` you are overwriting existing listener. Spinner can have only one `OnItemSelectedListener`...

Comment: Okay then what do I have to do? I need the second `OnItemSelectedListener`or else I can't change my images.

Comment: Nevermind it works now! I added my code to `listener` and now it show a Toast and the text change! Thanks for the help man! I would give you an upvote but don't have enough points!